# If I change the position of "To win the award" in this sentence, can I make this sentence right?

Tags: sentence

> To win the award, hard work is needed by Ed.

The sentence above is wrong, right? Though I don't clearly know about the reason why it is wrong. If I change the position of "To win the award", make the sentence become this one:
"Hard work is needed by Ed to win the award."
Is it better now? Or is it still wrong and strange?
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The most common expression would be something like this: *Ed must work hard to win the award.* Using any passive-voice version seems odd in this case, so it's difficult to really choose between them.

Comment: "To win the award, hard work is needed by Ed." The sentence above is wrong, right? - there is nothing wrong with that sentence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with *to win the award* in your original sentence.

Some people might refer to *to win the award* as a 'dangling modifier' since the syntactic subject of the main clause is *hard work* and, as their complaint might go, if the understood stubject of the 'dangling modifier' is not that of the main clause, then the sentence is poorly constructed -

> Is it the *hard work* that's winning the award?

However, as long as the context has made sufficiently clear who is winning the award - Ed ,or a group that Ed is a part of, or a person or group benefitted by Ed's work, etc. - there's really no need to worry about it.

What I would question more is *hard work is needed by Ed*, which seems to be a passivisation of:

> Ed needs hard work.

a very unidiomatic way of saying:

> Ed needs to work hard.

In fact, both the potential 'dangling modifier' problem, and the inelegance of the main clause would be solved by using the active voice:

> To win the award, Ed needs to work hard.